# Refactoring fat reducers

Tags: redux, refactoring, state

I'm working on my project using React-like approach and my problem is that my reducers are quite "flat", but they need to handle many updates in different state tree areas, so they're getting more and more complex.

For example, after dispatching action 'DO_SOMETHING', first I need to update my state within 3 LOC, but then, when the project grows and I need to work on additional features, someone wants to see base result + something extra after executing the same actions. So you can imagine, that after spending many weeks reducers are becoming 'fat' in a way that they are touching many different areas of the same tree, in the same pure way, but it's really hard to structure code inside them properly (one state tree and one store).

In most of the tutorials I can find only given scenario:

- dispatch 'ADD_TODO'
- update state, add new todo to the array of todos

while in my case it's like:

```
case SELECT_FILTER:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        oneProperty: ...,
        anotherProperty: null,
        nextProperty: false
        // and the logic is getting bigger and bigger
    })
```

- dispatch 'SELECT_FILTER'
- update applied filters section (UI summary of applied filters)
- update query which will be used to fetch data from server
- clear this
- copy that
- next month this filter should also...

:/

I've tried to create "sets of reducers" - filters reducers, list reducers, and so on, but the problem is that I'm working on the same page and incoming features introduces cross-cutting changes. Simple grouping was ok in smaller app, but now each reducer seems to be interested in too many parts of my state.

So my question is how to structure my reducers properly? Maybe I put too much "local state" into the state tree? Or something else? I'm looking forward to see your solutions related to composing and structuring reducers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conveniently, last year I wrote a section for the Redux docs called ["Structuring Reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) :) .  It demonstrates several useful techniques for organizing and composing reducer logic.  In particular, you might be interested in the sections on ["Beyond `combineReducers`"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html) and ["Reusing Reducer Logic"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ReusingReducerLogic.html).

My ["Practical Redux" tutorial series](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/series/practical-redux/) also demonstrates some more advanced reducer structures, particularly the post [Practical Redux, Part 7: Form Change Handling, Data Editing, and Feature Reducers](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/).

It may also be worth considering dispatching multiple "primitive" actions that could be dispatched in sequence to form larger behaviors.  For example, you might have a thunk that dispatches `BASIC_UPDATE`, `SPECIFIC_EXTRA_UPDATE_1`, and `SPECIFIC_EXTRA_UPDATE_2` in a row.  There are concerns regarding performance to be aware of with that, but it's a valid approach (and perf concerns can be resolved with various batching strategies).  For more info, see the Redux FAQ entries on [dispatching multiple actions](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Actions.html#actions-multiple-actions) and [reducing store notification events](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Performance.html#performance-update-events), my blog post [Idiomatic Redux: Thoughts on Thunks](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/), and the [Store#Store Change Subscriptions](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/) section of my Redux addons catalog.